# URL routing not working when publishing ASP .net website to IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I tried almost every possible way on internet. Its running perfectly when build with Visual studio 2010 but when i published it, the link that are routed are not working. The URL gets changed on click but the page remains the same.

**Global.asax**

```
static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("CityPage", "City.aspx/{City}.aspx", "~/AllCities.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("ProfessionPage", "Profession.aspx/{Profession}.aspx", "~/AllProfession.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("CompanyPage", "Company.aspx/{Company}.aspx", "~/AllCompany.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("NewspaperPage", "Newspaper.aspx/{Newspaper}.aspx","~/AllNewspaper.aspx");
        routes.MapPageRoute("DynamicPage", "{Description}.aspx", "~/DynamicPage.aspx");
    }
```

A link from **City.aspx**

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="<%$RouteUrl:City=Islamabad %>">Islamabad</asp:HyperLink><br />
```

The last **MapPageRoute** is working but the others (like the *City* one) are just changing the *URL* and the page remains the same.

Comment: Can you try removing the first ".aspx" in your second parameter? Ex. "City/{City}.aspx" instead of "City.aspx/{City}.aspx". That URL scheme is very unusual and your server might be interpreting things incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. :)

Comment: But the `HyperLink` is unclickable now. Whats the problem?

Comment: How is the link being rendered in HTML?